# Non-linear equation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I have no idea how I could solve this equation with matlab:

f(1)=0.098253*x(1)-atan((tan(x(1))-tan(x(2)))/2)*0.531268-0.433015*x(2)-0.27994

f(2)=0.9951*x(1)-atan((tan(x(1))-tan(x(2)))/2)*0.12909+0.866022*x(2)-0.350005;

I tryed with function = f and then [x,eval,flag]=fsolve('ecuaciones',x0); but I have an error:

Error in ==> fsolve at 254
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE
    cannot continue.

And Matlab says to me that is double type... but I have no idea how I can resolve!! I am new using Matlab, for that reason I need the answer clearly!!

THANK YOU!

Comment: Firstly what are you trying to solve for? I take it your solving for x(1) and x(2)

Comment: Are you trying to solve `f(2)-f(1)=0` ?

Comment: And what are you using for `x0`? Andd exactly what is your `ecuaciones` function? Real code wis appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your equations can be solved for anything  you've only one degree of freedom because f(2) is a multiple of f(1)